# Turning if statement into a single line while setting a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to check if something exists in a dictionary and then if it does, set it to a variable.

Here is what I am doing:

```
myobj = None
if myvar in mydict:
    myobj = mydict[myvar]
```

I got it down to this:

```
if myvar in mydict: myobj = mydict[myvar]
```

But what I am after is something like this (pseudo):

```
myobj = mydict[myvar] if myvar in mydict
```

Basically I am looking into a dictionary with a : layout. If my string is in the dictionary, then I want the value (class object) to be set my variable.

Comment: `myobj = mydict.get(myvar)`..

Comment: and you pseudocode is only missing an `else None`; `myobj = mydict[myvar] if myvar in mydict else None`, a verbose way of spelling `myobj = mydict.get(myvar)`.